# Add already existing axes or figures as subfigures to a new figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have four figure and axes objects that I want to add as subplots to a new figure. I.e. the following code:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=1)
ax1.plot(x1, y1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=2)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=3)
ax3.plot(x3, y3)

fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots(1, 1, num=4)
ax4.plot(x4, y4)
```

I want all the `ax1` to `ax4` to be subplots in a new figure `fig5`, something like this:
(This is **not** valid code, it's just for illustration purposes)

```
fig5 = plt.figure()
fig5.subplot(2, 2, 1) = ax1
fig5.subplot(2, 2, 2) = ax2
fig5.subplot(2, 2, 3) = ax3
fig5.subplot(2, 2, 4) = ax4
```

What is the best way to do this?

I'm using Matplotlib version 3.3.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not far off. You can just append it to the new one.

```
fig5 = plt.figure()
fig5.axes.append(ax1) # ax2 etc
```

Comment: I primarily use Spyder, and doing this I get this `<Figure size 1980x1500 with 0 Axes>` printed in the Spyder console, and no plot shows up. When I try to run it outside of Spyder, I only get a blank window, but no `<Figure ...` printed to the console. I have `plt.show()` at the end of the file. Is there anything else I should to do besides adding all the axes with `axes.append`?

Comment: Are you expecting the data to come across as well ? I don't think that is possible at least not to my knowledge. You would have to replot them to combine the different figures

Comment: Yes, I was expecting a carbon copy of the original plot. But if I that's not possible and I have to replot it I might have to rethink.

Comment: Yeah maybe define a function for your plotting so you only have to pass in your data

Comment: Same problem here, was this solved? No plot shows up after adding the objects to the new figure using `fig.axes.append`